# Restricting url to group 'argument of type 'ManyRelatedManager' is not iterable'

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to restrict certain urls to only be accessible to certain groups. I have added my user to the `staff` group and have a view to check with `user_passes_test` if the user is in the staff group. However when I go to this url I get `argument of type 'ManyRelatedManager' is not iterable`

**views.py**

```
def in_staff_group(user):
    return 'Staff' in user.groups

@login_required
@user_passes_test(in_staff_group)
def my_view(request):
    return render(request=request, template_name="main/template.html", context=context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the Queryset on the manager via `.all`, `.filter` or some other function that returns a Queryset.

```
def in_staff_group(user):
    return 'Staff' in user.groups.all()
```

Though I don't think that's right. You probably need something like:

```
def in_staff_group(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name_or_some_field='Staff').exists()
```

Comment: `Cannot resolve keyword 'name_or_some_field' into field. Choices are: id, name, permissions, user` when trying your second solution.

Comment: Heh, we have a bit of a misunderstanding. `name_or_some_field` was meant to be changed into "name or some field" that's relevant to your model not actually `name_or_some_field`.

Comment: Ah I thought so.. Relevant to my user model? I thought maybe `return user.groups.filter('Staff' in user.groups).exists()` might work but I got my original error.

Comment: Solved by changing it to return user.groups.filter(name='Staff').exists()